# Array to string conversion Line Number: 56

Tags: codeigniter

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: views/editslideshows.php
>
> Line Number: 56
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\companygiondaci\application\views\editslideshows.php
>   Line: 56
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\companygiondaci\application\controllers\Cpages.php
>   Line: 310
>   Function: view
>
> File: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\companygiondaci\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

views/editslideshows.php

```
<?php foreach ($images as $images_item): ?>
<?php echo $images; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

controllers/Cpages.php

```
public function editslideshow() {

    $image_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $data['images'] = $this->Mpages->call_point_slideshow($image_id);

    $this->load->view('editslideshows', $data);

}
```

models/Mpages.php

```
public function call_point_slideshow($image_id)
{
    $this->db->where('image_id', $image_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('slideshow');
    return $query->result();

}
```

Comment: Please mansion Line Number: 56

Comment: this is good reading http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 2):

In your view page `views/editslideshows.php`

You used echo directly `<?php echo $images; ?>` that's why you getting error.

You can use `$images_item->db_field_name`. that's means any field name from your `slideshow` table

bellow my correction :

```
<?php foreach ($images as $images_item): ?>
<?php echo $images_item->db_field_name; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view

```
<?php foreach ($images as $images_item) { ?>

<h3><?php echo $images_item->field_name; ?></h3>

<?php } ?>
```